# Debugging Tabs in Microsoft teams bot framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm new to bot development in Microsoft teams, i'm using bot framework for development. I want to know how we can debug the tabs in MS Teams from our local solution.
For debugging of my message extension i'm using ngrok, so kindly suggest some way to debug the tabs in similar fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#tunnel-using-ngrok) to debug your Tabs as well. You can specify your ngrok URL as Tab's contentURL and you will get the debug points for server side code.

Please take a look at [DevTools for Microsoft Teams tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools) for client side debugging.